# Use or store serial data and access from other class-Java

Tags: java, serial-port, rxtx

Hi i am new to serial programming.I am trying to return serial data from one class to another , This is my code(Using RXTX libraries)

```
class XXX implements SerialPortEventListener{

    final int[] val = new int[2];

    public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        String storeId;
        String status; 

        if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
            try {
                String inputLine = input.readLine();
                String[] arrayValues = inputLine.split(" ");
                storeId=arrayValues[0];
                status=arrayValues[1];
                light=Integer.parseInt(storeId);
                lightstatus = Integer.parseInt(status);

                //System.out.println(light);
                //System.out.println(status);
                val[0] = light;
                val[1] = lightstatus;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
        }  
    }

    public int send(){
        return val[0];
    }

    public int sendst(){
        return val[1];
    }
}
```

Reading and printing the data in this class is succesful, But accessing the value out of this returns null...any help would be appreciated..Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Reading and printing the data in this class is succesful, But
>   accessing the value out of this returns null...

Based in your code I see you're following this example: [Event Based Two Way Communication](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Event_based_two_way_Communication) (if you are not then you should take a look). As its title says it's an event based way of read/write through serial port.

Having said this, I strongly suspect you're trying to do something like this:

```
XXX serialPortListener = new XXX();
int light = serialPortListener.send();
int lightStatus = serialPortListener.sendst();
```

It's most likely that `send()` and `sendst()` return `null` or `0` because no `SerialPortEvent` has happened yet when these methods are called. So if you're working in an event driven scenario then it makes sense keep in this framework. How? For instance implementing an [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern):

1) Make `XXX` class extend from `Observable` and perform this little change:

```
public class XXX extends Observable implements SerialPortEventListener {

    int[] val = new int[2];

    public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        String storeId;
        String status; 
        if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
            try {
                // all your code here
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
        }  
    }

    ...
}
```

2) Another class has to implement `Observer` interface:

```
public class MyObserver implements Observer {

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        if(o instanceof XXX){
            XXX observable = (XXX) o;
            System.out.println("Light: " + observable.send());
            System.out.println("Light status: " + observable.sendst());
        }
    }
}
```

3) Append a `MyObserver` object to `XXX` instance:

```
XXX serialPortListener = new XXX();
serialPortListener.addObserver(new MyObserver());
```

That's it. Every time a `SerialPortEvent` is processed the observer will be notified and it will successfuly read the values.